# Report Builder optional and obligatory parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters, optional-parameters, reportbuilder

I have a problem with my report from a live query. In my report i have 5 parameters that allow to pick a date range `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo` and 3 parameters which should allow to select specific attributes:

```
@salesid, @batch, @serial
```

I want to make date range parameters mandatory and that's working without any problems but last 3 parameters: `@salesid`, `@batch`, `@serial` should be optional.

But they do not work as they should. Last 3 parameters should let you type in value which would work as filters. But when I pick date and one of those parameters Im getting the entire value of the query instead of selected values.

In parameters properties I slected "Allow blank value (" ")" option and just in case I defined a default value as blank.

That's how conditions in my query looks like:

```
where
    st.custaccount <> 'number%'
    and datepart(year,st.CREATEDDATETIME) >= 2012
    and (ita.VENDORCODE like'producer1' or ita.vendorcode like 'producer2')
    and st.createddatetime >= @FromDate
    and st.createddatetime <= @ToDate  
     or (st.salesid = @salesid or @salesid  is null)
     or (itd.INVENTBATCHID = @batch or @batch is null)
     or (itd.INVENTSERIALID = @serial or @serial is null)
```

Theoretically it should work but... Well but in practice it's not.

How to set a condition to get the desired effect? I couldn't find anything helpful so far. If any of you know something useful please give me some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your final 3 `or` statements to `and` statements.

At the moment, your query is essentially checking for data items that match your criteria ***OR*** that any of those final three parameters is matched/null.  This means that even if you data isn't the date range etc it will still be returned:

```
where st.custaccount <> 'number%'
    and st.CREATEDDATETIME >= '20120101'    -- Try not to use functions in your WHERE clause, as this stops indexes from working, making your query less efficient.
    and ita.VENDORCODE in('producer1', 'producer2')    -- IN has the same effect.
    and st.createddatetime between @FromDate and @ToDate    -- BETWEEN is an inclusive date range.  Equivalent to >= and <=

    and (st.salesid = @salesid
        or @salesid is null
        )
    and (itd.INVENTBATCHID = @batch
        or @batch is null
        )
    and (itd.INVENTSERIALID = @serial
        or @serial is null
        )
```

Comment: I tried it earlier. And it kind of working and kind of not. To be more specyfic it's working for salesid and batch but it isn't working for last parameter serial. 

I forgot to mention that it didn't worked earlier at all with 2nd parameter or 3rd because I forgot to add option "allow null value" in parameters properties. But still 3rd parameter is unusable as sole parameter to filter results.

Answering your comments im not using any functions there i just didn't wanted to post specyfic values of a client so i changed it for what you saw.

Still your reply kind of answer my question.

Comment: And thanks for hints including in and between, it's really helpful :)